# auto delete of records in a dolphindb stream table

Tags: dolphindb

Does DolphinDB support auto delete of records in a stream table? For example, I wanted to delete some records that exceed the given length or are outdated?

The real-time data are useless after a certain time but their storage takes up lots of memory. Can I schedule a delete operation on the records from an hour ago in a DolphinDB stream table?

Answer (score 0):

```
enableTableShareAndPersistence(table, tableName, [asynWrite=true], [compress=true], [cacheSize=-1], [retentionMinutes=1440], [flushMode=0], [preCache])
```

I would recommend you persist the stream table to disk in DolphinDB.

Set the parameter *cacheSize* to specify how many rows at most the table can keep, and the rest of data will be persisted to disk.

Also you can set the parameter *retentionMinutes*, indicating how long the persisted file will be retained on disk. The default time is a day and you can modify the value as small as you want.